# how to develop a date picker in Jquery mobile to cover entire mobile screen when it pops up

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI datepicker to display the datepicker for my mobile application. I am re using the CSS and JS files from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. My requirement is, when the datepicker popup it should hide the background screen and user should not have any control over the main screen until he/she chooses the date. It should work on all mobile devices. Can anybody provide the solution for this?

This is my sample HTML page that have created to test the similar functionality.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>




  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>


  function focusTextBox(){
  var a=2;
 var tb = document.getElementById('datepicker');
 if(a==2){
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+18M +0D", showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true, dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],showButtonPanel: true });
  });
}else{

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 1, maxDate: "+18M +0D" });
  });

}
 tb.focus();



}
  </script>


</head>
<body>
</br>
</br>

  <input type="radio" id="myradio" name="radiobt" onClick="javascript:focusTextBox();">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using something else. 
I've used mobiscroll on a project of mine. It's targeting mobile devices.
It has tons of features. What you want is called a modal display 
on mobiscroll. Check it out here http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/time

Select "Modal" on the "Display" selector and scroll down to see a live demo.

**UPDATE**

> The Date & Time Scroller, Select, Image & Text and Treelist Scrollers
>   are under the MIT License and are free to use

from [here](http://mobiscroll.com/faq)

**UPDATE 2**

Jquery mobile and jquery ui don't work well in general. Since you want to solve this with datepicker from jquery ui, you either have to find a way to put the dynamic datepicker div into a dialog or when the datepicker is shown, disable the page by having a div the size of the page which will absorb all the clicks outside the datepicker and disable the functionality that exits the datepicker when click outside of it. It's a lot of work I think.

Comment: mobiscroll is the paid version. I dont want that solution .Appreciate if you could provide the solution using Jquery ui.

Comment: The Date & Time Scroller, Select, Image & Text and Treelist Scrollers are under the MIT License and are free to use